# Reputation graph in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Please could the iOS app have some way of viewing (and perhaps filtering) the reputation graph on my network profile?

I find that graph motivating.

Comment: I'd also like to thank the devs for a great app! Normally apps are annoying and frustrating, but this one is nice.